# Outputting a different structure in Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Let's say I have the following model:

```py
class Attribute(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    value = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

How could I get a Django REST Framework serializer to render it as the following?

```
{
    attribute {
        'name' : 'shoes',
        'code': 'sho',
        'group': {
            'name' : 'shoes',
            'code': 'sho'
         }
    },
    value': 1
}
```

**Edit:** My current serializer, which doesn't get it exactly correct:

```py
from collections import namedtuple

Group = namedtuple('Group', ('name code'))


class GroupSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
    code = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)


class AttributeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()
    code = serializers.CharField()
    value = serializers.IntegerField()
    group = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Attribute
        fields = ('name', 'code', 'value', 'group')

    def get_group(self, obj):
        serializer = GroupSerializer(
            Group(name=obj.name, code=obj.code),
        )
        return serializer.data
```

Comment: Where did this group coming from?

Comment: share your serializer too

Comment: @a_k_v the `group` is a mirror of `name` and `code`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best  bet would be to override serializer's `to_representation`.

And return the structure which you want.

Something like this:

```
class AttributeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()
    code = serializers.CharField()
    value = serializers.IntegerField()
    group = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Attribute
       fields = ('name', 'code', 'value', 'group')

    def get_group(self, obj):
        serializer = GroupSerializer(
            Group(name=obj.name, code=obj.code),
        )
        return serializer.data

    def to_representation(self, instance):

        output = super().to_representation(instance)

        value = output.pop('value')

        return {"attribute"  : output, 'value' : value}
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is 
View.py

```
class AttributeView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = AttributeSerializer
    queryset = Attribute.objects.all()

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(dict({"Attribute": serializer.data}))
```

model.py

```
class Attribute(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    value = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    @property
    def get_group(self):
        return dict({"name": self.name, "code": self.code})
```

serializer.py

```
class AttributeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    group = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='get_group')
    class Meta:
        model = Attribute
        fields = ('name', 'code', 'value', 'group')
```

Comment: I didn't know you could add a `get_` property to the model like that, very neat.